# Deploying react/apollo-server app onto Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

What I'm trying to do is deploy react / apollo-server full stack app to heroku. Thus I' trying to serve static client files from express/apollo-server backend, like this:

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');

const { schema } = require('./schema');
const { resolvers } = require('./resolvers');

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
});

server.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

For some reason I don't understand client is not served while deployed to heroku. On heroku URL I'm getting: `GET query missing.` If I set graphql to enabled in production I can see it, I can play with resolving data. But client is not rendered. I'm guseing app.get with * is not working and then index.html is not catched.

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are only exposing the `server` from `ApolloServer` to the port 4000 and not exposing the `app` with the frontend client application.

In order to have the fullstack app deployed, you also have to expose the `app`, in order to do that you can use `applyMiddleware` from `ApolloServer` and bind both apollo server and the frontend client, something like:

```
.....

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
});

server.applyMiddleware({
  path: '/my-frontend', // you should change this to whatever you want
  app,
});

app.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }, () => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at http://localhost:4000`);
});
```

Now you should be able to navigate to `http://localhost:4000/my-frontend` and see your client application.