# React typescript graphql app heroku - GET query missing

Tags: heroku, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to deploy an super simple react graphql app to heroku

The app deploys but when I go the the site url I get `GET query missing`

I have a Procfile  with `web: yarn dev` this server package.json look like

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\" "
  },
```

On the server have

models/Font.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const fontSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

schema.js

```
exports.typeDefs = `

    type Font{
        _id: String
        name: String
        description: String
    }

    type Query{
        fonts: [Font]
    }

`   

module.exports = mongoose.model('Font', fontSchema)
```

resolvers.js

```
exports.resolvers = {

    Query:{
        fonts: async(obj, args, {Font}, info) => {
            const allFonts = await Font.find()
            return allFonts
        }
    }

}
```

server.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config({path: 'variables.env'});

const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server');
const {typeDefs} = require('./schema');
const {resolvers} = require('./resolvers');

const Font = require('./models/Font');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    playground: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
    context:{
        Font
    }
})

mongoose    
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{
        useNewUrlParser:true,
        useUnifiedTopology:true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('bd connected'))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))

server.listen({port: PORT})
    .then(({url}) => console.log(`server listening on ${url}`))
```

On the client I have

client/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http'
import {ApolloClient} from 'apollo-client'
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo'
import {ApolloProvider as ApolloProviderHooks} from 'react-apollo-hooks'

const cache = new InMemoryCache()
const link = new HttpLink({
  // uri:'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
  uri:'https://infinite-badlands-93099.herokuapp.com/graphql'
  //uri:'/graphql'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link
})

const Root = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)


ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <ApolloProviderHooks client={client}>
      <Root />
    </ApolloProviderHooks>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

client/App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

import {FontData} from './generated/fontData';
import {useQuery} from 'react-apollo-hooks';
import {GET_ALL_FONTS} from './queries'

function App() {

  const {data, loading} = useQuery<FontData>(GET_ALL_FONTS, {
    suspend:false
  })

  if(loading || !data) return <div>Loading</div>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Fonts</h1>
      <ul>
        {
          data && data.fonts && data.fonts.map(font => (
          <li key={font?._id || ''} data-id={font?._id}>
            {font?.name}
          </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

client/queries

```
import {gql} from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_ALL_FONTS = gql `
    query FontData{
        fonts{
            _id
            name
            description
        }
    }
`
```

On heroku I have Config Var `NODE_ENV = production` and `MONGO_URI = the mongodb address and password`

If I set `playground: true` in the server.js the graphql playground appears when I go to the url but I want the actual site front end to display. The playground works and I can write queries that work

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    playground: true,
    context:{
        Font
    }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62638961/6124657 - the same problem - graphql server not serving static content (frontend)

Comment: I'm not using a HTTP GET endpoint though

Comment: yes, you're - check in browser dev tools/network - "entering url" results in GET request :D

Comment: So `apollo-server` works locally but not when deployed?

Comment: no, apollo works, react doesn't work :D  locally react app is served on other port - builded (react public dir) content needs to be served as static - can be served separately (f.e. using cdn) or integrated like downloads above (special apollo config)

Comment: So I shouldn't be using `apollo-server` then

Comment: you can try solution from older Daniel's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478478/6124657

Comment: Thanks for your help