# Expose HTTP GET API in GraphQL Apollo Server v2.0

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using Apollo Server v2.0 (without middleware) as part of my project and I would like to add support for a HTTP GET endpoint to for file downloads. Is there a way to expose an API endpoint without using apollo-server-express?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. While `apollo-server` currently uses `express` under the hood, the Express instance is not exposed as a property on the `ApolloServer` instance. In order to expose any additional endpoints, you'd need to migrate to `apollo-server-express` or any of the other available framework integrations. The migration is relatively painless since the APIs are almost identical.